Why it has to have a default return value when implementing binary insertion using recursion?
The searchInsert function return the index where the target should be based on the value. Why it should have the line
return -1;

in the following code? I thought I included all the possible outcomes when narrowing the range in the array of *nums. Once I comment it ,the result goes wrong.
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int searchInsert(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int s = 0;
    int b = numsSize-1;
    //the special case in the first place
    if(target > nums[b]){
        return numsSize;
    };
    if(target <= nums[s]){
        return 0;
    };
    //do the main process
    return narrow(nums, s, b, target);
}


int middleF(int s, int b){
    return (b+s)/2;
}


int narrow(int* nums, int s, int b, int target){
    //set middle
    int middle = middleF(s,b);
    //easy conditon
    if(target == nums[middle]){
        return middle;
    };
    if(target == nums[s]){
        return s;
    };
    if(target == nums[b]){
        return b;
    };
    if(b-s == 1){
        return s+1;
    };
    //narrow
    if(target < nums[middle]){
        return narrow(nums, s, middle, target);
    };
    if(target > nums[middle]){
        return narrow(nums, middle, b, target);
    };
    
    return -1;
}
int main(){
    int arr[]  = {1,3,5,6};
    //supposed to be 2
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,5));
    //supposed to be 1
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,2));
    //supposed to be 4
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,7));
}

I try to search if there has to be a default return value even if the actual case will not happened when compiling in C. But haven't find something useful yet.
It turns out to be certain compiler's warning and not wrong on other compiler:
Line 40: Char 1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] [solution.c]
   43 | }
      | ^


Why do you think that line is necessary?

Is the case target == nums[middle] covered? If it is, it is probably not somthing the compiler can prove and is complaining about not all of the paths returning a value. In order to ensure all paths are covered, one should use if/else, and not distinct ifs.

@EugeneSh. That's the first case the function checks.

There should be a link from the question to the staging ground, where this question was discussed. All the helpful comments are gone.

@jabaa if you know where to look you can find it in the history, though I totally agree. It should be more visible

https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78863352#comment139043209_78863352

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Where do I have to look? In the history, I can only see "
created from staging ground", but without link. Or do I need more reputation?

@jabaa same table right-most colum (the "comment" column) "Graduated from staging ground post." is a link

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I guess, it's a reputation thing. I don't have a comment column. Only "created from staging ground
occurred 16 mins ago"

Unrelated: You could simplify it very much by not using recursion. A loop will do fine. example

@Yi Lin Not all compilers are so smart to analyze correctly a bad code.:) Pay attention to that your code will invoke undefined behavior if for example the user will pass numsSize equal to zero. And the function searchInsert should be declared like size_t searchInsert( const int* nums, size_t numsSize, int target);

As I noted when the question was in the staging area —— Style guide: the null statements after the close brace in if (target == nums[middle]) { return middle; }; etc are not a good idea. Remove the semicolon after the brace. Sometimes, you need a semicolon after a brace (initializers, in particular; also after defining a structure or union type). Often, you don't need one — not after the close brace for a compound statement (including a function body). Note that those semicolons would make else into a syntax error.  This is a stylistic issue since you don't use an else clause.

You get the error message because the code is compiled with the compiler option
-Werror=return-type

This causes the compiler to break compilation with an error, if a path in a value-returning function doesn't return a value.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror_003d

-Werror=
Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended; for example -Werror=switch turns the warnings controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate -Werror for specific warnings; for example -Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect.
The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning. That option can then be used with -Werror= and -Wno-error= as described above. (Printing of the option in the warning message can be disabled using the -fno-diagnostics-show-option flag.)
Note that specifying -Werror=foo automatically implies -Wfoo. However, -Wno-error=foo does not imply anything.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wreturn-type

-Wreturn-type
Warn whenever a function is defined with a return type that defaults to int (unless -Wimplicit-int is active, which takes precedence). Also warn if execution may reach the end of the function body, or if the function does not contain any return statement at all.
Attempting to use the return value of a non-void function other than main that flows off the end by reaching the closing curly brace that terminates the function is undefined.
Unlike in C, in C++, flowing off the end of a non-void function other than main results in undefined behavior even when the value of the function is not used.
This warning is enabled by default in C++ and by -Wall otherwise.

The compiler isn't able to detect, that this code is unreachable. It's a false-positive. Even with this flag and without return -1; you shouldn't get a warning or error. Here is a simpler example, where the compiler can detect, that all possible paths have a return statement and there is no error or warning:
int f() {
    if (1)
        return 1;
}

int main() {
    return f();
}

https://godbolt.org/z/zacYxMjqP
As you can see on Godbolt, it works without
return -1;

https://godbolt.org/z/zsnrsM9x3
and according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return, it's well-defined:

Reaching the end of any other value-returning function is undefined behavior if the result of the function is used in an expression (it is allowed to discard such return value).

That's not the case in your code.
A better solution is to use the last possible return value as default:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int middleF(int s, int b){
    return (b+s)/2;
}

int narrow(int* nums, int s, int b, int target){
    //set middle
    int middle = middleF(s,b);
    //easy conditon
    if(target == nums[middle]){
        return middle;
    }
    if(target == nums[s]){
        return s;
    }
    if(target == nums[b]){
        return b;
    }
    if(b-s == 1){
        return s+1;
    }
    //narrow
    if(target < nums[middle]){
        return narrow(nums, s, middle, target);
    }

    return narrow(nums, middle, b, target);
}

int searchInsert(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int s = 0;
    int b = numsSize-1;
    //the special case in the first place
    if(target > nums[b]){
        return numsSize;
    }
    if(target <= nums[s]){
        return 0;
    }
    //do the main process
    return narrow(nums, s, b, target);
}

int main(){
    int arr[]  = {1,3,5,6};
    //supposed to be 2
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,5));
    //supposed to be 1
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,2));
    //supposed to be 4
    printf("%d",searchInsert(arr,4,7));
}

This way you don't have the unnecessary return value and the warning/error.

It's not necessary to rely on the return value not being used to judge that the program is ok as originally written.  The return -1 is unreachable.  Even without it and without otherwise modifying the logic, control flow through that function will always reach a return statement.  Thus, a potentially more interesting observation is that compilers are not perfect, especially when it comes to things like flow analysis.

@JohnBollinger TBH as I started with this question, I thought the missing return -1; is UB. I searched for a reference and this was the only quote on cppreference regarding UB and missing return statements I've found. The important part is not, if the expression is used. The important part is, that function flow has to actually reach this. I didn't know it. I thought, every path has to have a return statement, even if it's not reachable. This answer is actually for me and not for the OP.
